# Operate with index in a column of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

I have a dataframe called "d" with 11 variables and 170 rows. I want to operate with the values in 9,10 and 11th (d$CH4, d$CO2, d$N2O) and to create a new df dr$CH4, dr$CO2, dr$N2O columns saving the results of the operations. It consists of a series of substractions. I did it one by one. for the 9th column (d$CH4) it goes as follows: d[2,9] - d[1-9] then d[4,9] - d[3-9] , d[6,9] - d[5-9] and so on ending with one column (dr$CH4) and 85 rows with the results of each substraction. Then I would repeat the process with the other two columns. basically every odd row minus its previous even row.
I tried this but it would just give an empty df as output.

```
dr<- d[,9:11]
dr[,1:3] <- NA  #saving the names of the columns
j<-0

for (i in d$CH4){   
    dr[j,1] <- d[(i+1),9] - d[i, 9]
    j+1

}
```

Comment: Please provide a small sample of your data using `dput()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a solution without any loop - you can just shift your data.frame by one and then subtract the original one, e.g.:

```
d <- data.frame(matrix(runif(170*11), ncol=11, nrow=170))
dr<- d[,9:11] #getting subset
dr_help <- dr[2:nrow(d),] #shifting
result <- dr_help - dr[1:(nrow(dr)-1),] #calculation (equal to i+1 - i)
```

Also, please note that your new data.frame is one shorter than the original one because you can not calculate the last entry as `i+1` would be greater than `nrow(d)`.